# How does magento check if user is logged in order page

Tags: php, magento

I am still pretty new to Magento, and I was wondering how Magento is checking if a user is logged in in the `magento/index.php/sales/order/view/order_id/102/` page.

For example if a user who is not related to this order try to go there, he will be redirected to his own order history page. But I can't see this function neither in info.php nor in info.phtml in the sales/order directories (template and block).

I am asking this because I would like to use this feature as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verification is done in the controller. The controller responsible for order details page is `Mage_Sales_OrderController` that extends `Mage_Sales_Controller_Abstract`.  And in `Mage_Sales_Controller_Abstract` there is this method `_canViewOrder` that checks if the order has a visible status and if the order customer is the same as the logged in customer

```
protected function _canViewOrder($order)
{
    $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
    $availableStates = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates();
    if ($order->getId() && $order->getCustomerId() && ($order->getCustomerId() == $customerId)
        && in_array($order->getState(), $availableStates, $strict = true)
        ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it seems to be really this function, but do you know where it is called please ? In `OrderController `there does not seem to be a viewAction function.

Comment: Look in the parent class. `Mage_Sales_Controller_Abstract`. There should be a viewAction in there that calls `_loadValidOrder` that calls `_canViewOrder`

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed in the abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

```
//just call this helper function 
$isLoggedIn = $this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
```